# Copying one enum to other java

Tags: java, enums

I have one enum lets say `enum A { value1, value2, value3}` and there is one more `enum B { value1, value2, value3}` Even though these enums have similar values they can not be used interchangably because of coding standards as they reside in different tiers. Is there any way to copy the contents from one to other? Values do not have any access specifiers by default nor they have any type. They are just fields. Please let me know if there is any way to copy contents of one to other using java. Also Please note that A is a third party enum which can not be modified, B is the one which I am trying to generate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get an enum value by its name:

```
String name = A.value1.name();

try {
    B b = B.valueOf(name);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Handle this if name doesn't exist in B
}
```

The name is just a string and can be safely transferred between your different tiers. For more info, see the Javadoc of [`Enum.valueOf(Class<?>, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)

Comment: This is valid if the B enumeration values are a strict superset of those of A, with the same names. If this is not the case, e.g. because the names are different, or because many A values correspond to a single B value, OP will have to bite the bullet and create a pair of methods to do the conversion using a switch over the values of A to return the corresponding B and vice versa.

Comment: @JavierMartín: Well ;-) But my answer *does seem* to answer the OPs *specific* question, right?

Comment: If the enums were those in the example, yes, but later OP adds that "these enums have similar values". If they are *similar* (not *the same*), a conversion function would be a better option. Once you start adding the exceptional case as you have, code starts becoming more convoluted, whereas a pair of conversion functions would centralize the logic and any complications. From "user" code, the function call is never longer, and nearly always tidier, than the example you showed. Such functions can use code very similar to your example, or resort to a full `switch` if needed.

Comment: @JavierMartín: Why don't you add your own answer?

Comment: Because I'm on mobile and it was hard enough to write that from the phone keyboard :(
And besides, my "comment-answer" would be the same as option 3 from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the **names** of the enum constants are the same, you could get the string from one type using the `.name()` method and look for it in the other type using the `.valueOf()` method (As per Lukas Eder's answer.) The `java.lang.Enum` class defines a generic `.valueOf()`, but when you define a new `enum`, it also has an implicit method with that name that does not need the concrete enum type class as the first parameter - this is not very obvious from Javadocs.
2. If the **positions** of the declared constants correspond in both enums, get the position of the first type via the `.ordinal()` method, then the corresponding constant from the other type via `.values()[position]`. When you define a new `enum`, it has an implicit `.values()` method that returns all the constants in an array in the order in which they were defined - this is not very obvious from Javadocs.

I guess both these methods may be error prone, especially when constants are added/changed. You may not know that the 3rd party enum was updated and the above would then cause hard-to-trace bugs, as the relationship between the two enum classes is implied, but may not be known to the next developer working on this.

I personally would prefer:

3. Add from/to translation method(s) in the enum type that you have control over. Explicitly provide the relevant counterpart constant for each and every constant - probably by using a `switch` construct, which some IDEs can automatically populate with all the needed `case` statements. In the `default` statement, throw an exception (or other means of detecting an error), with a nice friendly message that this method needs to be updated. You will still get errors, but at least you can make it much clearer to whoever will be working on it when it occurs.

   This has the obvious advantage that neither names nor ordinal positions need to correspond. This may also be important if the enum value is saved to a database - depending on the schema used, you would want control over the constants, which you will not have with the 3rd party code.

On rereading your question it seems that you would want your enumB to be kept up to date with the values from the 3rd party enumA automatically, via a mechanism like reflection. It seems only inspection is allowed but not modification at runtime (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumMembers.html). Depending on your code, maybe another structure would fill the gap, e.g. a map with keys from the 3rd party enumA (which you can set up/update at runtime).

**Edit:** Seems that there are ways and means, but it is certainly not standard Java and for that reason I personally would not want to go there. See http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html.